# ethLogFlowable: how to get event args?

Tags: web3j

I am using ethLogFlowable to subscribe to an event and read the args of the event, in my case an address and a uint256 value.

I have followed this answer [stackExchangeLink](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64856/web3j-how-to-get-event-args-when-parsing-logs), but I am always getting only one element from topics which is the my-event-hash.

Here is my code:

```
        filter.addSingleTopic(my_event_hash);
        MainActivity.web3j.ethLogFlowable(filter).subscribe(log -> {
                System.out.println("Event equal "+log);
             Address arg1 = (Address) FunctionReturnDecoder.decodeIndexedValue(log.getTopics().get(1), new TypeReference<Address>() {});
            System.out.println("----ARG1: "+arg1);

        });
```

The application crash as `log.getTopics` contains only one element `hash_event`

Any idea? please.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add the definition of this event from your solidity contract.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code below and it is working now for me. The arguments can be extracted from getParameters as follow:

```
List<Type> args = FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(
                    log.getData(), my_event.getParameters());
System.out.println("Seller : "+args(0).getValue());
System.out.println("Price  : "+args(1).getValue());
```

And this is the solidity definition of the event:

```
 event OfferAccepted (address _seller, uint _price);
```